# Is marriage a financially sound decision?

Tags: marriage, divorce

I am a 29 year old male with average salary and I have been considering marriage, mostly out of peer pressure. When I was thinking about it, an obvious question came up:

Is marriage ever a financially sound decision in the long term for a person like me, considering the chances of a skewed divorce and the cost of child rearing? What will be the future (10 - 20 years) consequences of marrying now?

It is obvious that the experience and dynamics of marriage will be very different for me compared to one of my parents or grandparents.

Comment: Are you asking generally about a hypothetical marriage to some unknown person, or is there a specific person you are considering marrying? Is this specific person good with money? Spendy? Irresponsible? High-income? Already very wealthy? Heavily in debt?

Comment: You are not asking about JUST marriage, but about possible choices you might make after marriage, such as child-rearing and divorce.  There are just too many variables involved to give a general answer.

Answer (score 15):

There are situations where I'd advise against marriage for financial reasons, but never for it if your heart isn't in it.

It sounds like you aren't ready for marriage and finances shouldn't even be part of the equation.

Answer (score 6):

“Peer pressure” is an awfully bad reason for marriage.

Cost of child rearing: For the money you pay, you get the enjoyment of seeing your kids growing up. You decide if it’s worth it. If you don’t want children, don’t get married to someone who doesn’t 100% agree.

Financial risk due to divorce: Don’t underestimate the risk that you might get married to a financially irresponsible person. I can only say, find the right person, one that can stand on their own two feet, don’t do anything that will make them want revenge, and talk to a lawyer before you get married.

Comment: Peer pressure is a pretty bad reason for anything.

Comment: When most of your friends are married and small minority that is not married is engaged or in LTR things become scarry. Dating pool dries up with each day and friends i used to go out with tied the knot. It seems like marriage is only straightforward and uncomplicated way to avoid loneliness at my age.